# Using Python pyodbc to store SQL Server OpLock

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm writing a python script which extracts data from an SQL server table, and need to store the latest oplock value between script runs. This is what I have so far for the part that get the Oplock:

```py
def get_oplock():
    try:
        mydbSage = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=SO1-SQL-V\Sage;'
                      'Database=Live;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=Yes;')

        Sagecursor = mydbSage.cursor()

        oplockQuery = """SELECT TOP 1 OpLock FROM SOPOrderReturn ORDER BY OpLock DESC"""

        Sagecursor.execute(oplockQuery)

        newOplock = str(Sagecursor.fetchone()[0])

        f = open("oplock.txt", "w")
        f.write(newOplock)
        f.close()

        mydbSage.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        print('MainError:', e)
 
    finally:
        Sagecursor.close()
        mydbSage.close()
```

This works, but rather than the expected Oplock format (e.g. 0x0000000010C33B70) I get something like `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\xc3?\x82'`

I don't fully understand this format or what its called specifically, but I tried converting it to a timestamp using the below which appears to work, but in practice doesn't seem to be right as it doesn't output newer rows when used in a select query.

I had to remove the b at the start to get the convert to work, so not sure if thats why it hasn't worked.

```sql
CONVERT(timestamp, '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\xc3?\x82')
```

Is anyone able to advise how I can get this working? Hopefully I've explained it clearly.

Comment: The `b` prefix indicates a _bytes literal_ in Python 2.6+. This is logical since your expected `0x0000000010C33B70` is a varbinary constant in SQL Server, equivalent to a byte array. That said, though, it looks like Python mangled it assuming UTF-8 encoding where none exists.

Comment: What is the column type? And `timestamp` is a rowversion number in binary, not an actual time

Comment: @Charlieface The column type in SQL is timestamp.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning any idea how to get around that?

Comment: I think it's already a `bytes` object in Python, that's just how it displays it, and converting a `timestamp` column to `timestamp` is obviously pointless. By the way, `timestamp` syntax is deprecated, you should use `rowversion` instead (which is the same thing)